# Designing a Tournament Schema

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I am designing a Tournament Schema for Scrabble tournaments, including Leagues and Rounds for each Tournament. The following is the initial schema design we have.

[image]

A Tournament has many leagues, a league has many rounds, and a round has many games. What we can't work out is where we store the players without generating many-to-many relationships.

We're looking for ways in which we can improve the design from here as I'm not sure this is going to work as is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the schema provided, what is the purpose of the `PlayerID` link between `League` and `Player`? If this is to determine if a player is participating in that league you would need to duplicate each `League` record for every player in that league which would break your primary key. In order to determine if a player is part of a League you would need to join from `League` through `Round` and `Game` to `Player`.

I believe this link can be removed and the `PlayerID` column in `League` dropped. This will resolve any many-to-many relationship issues that I can see.

Also you are storing the players name in both `Player` and `Game`, is this required for history or can this be normalised and use the data in the `Player` table throughout the implementation?

Comment: Thanks for this, we came to the same conclusion after looking into the schema a little more. It makes a lot more sense!

Comment: Excellent, good to know you are actively trying to solve the problem and improve your knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

If a player can move from one league to another after each season, I wouldn't put the scores in the Player table or you would lose all history. Instead you can have a Ranking table with relationships to `League` and `Player`.